# Testing the web API services through sql profiler?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web-services, asp.net-web-api

**I need help testing web api through sql profiler**.

I tested with chrome advanced rest client and fiddler but i need to test with profiler, so I can know which method is really slow and  i can insert different things in that

For example, if there are three thing in a method I can test by inserting one at a time; I can't do the same thing with fiddler or rest client service.

Thanks for Helping.

Comment: You still want to use a rest client service. You want to run in the SQL Prifiler in addition to that. Also, you should probably be able to infer what db operations are executed by which request you send to the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wonderful question , i been searching for this and finally i found this link 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163749.aspx
It should help you out .One question , are you using locally or on the server.This matters for profiler

Comment: Damn it! The link is not working... I think it's too old. Was it an article from June 2013 ?

Comment: -1 - Link rot, and a shining example why link-only answers are highly discouraged on SO. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Answer (score 1):

Just do EXEC sp_proc name , for all those 3 in your ssms , you should be able to see all the slowness and everything

Answer (score 1):

try using sql profiler too , because profiler can trace those out

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, SQL Profiler would not be able to send an HTTP GET/POST/etc request to a web browser. That's why Chrome and Fiddler (any many other clients, such as [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org) and [RESTClient](https://code.google.com/p/rest-client/)) can be used - they make the right HTTP posts.

In our web service design, we have the the API talk to the database via stored procedures. These stored procedures can easily link back with certain calls to the database from the web API.

As an example, a call to an API such as `/api/products` may call 3 different stored procedures. With SQL Profiler, you'll be able to see when the 3 calls were made, as well as which parameters were sent in.

Comment: I know in sql server  i can do EXEC sp_sample,and keep the profiler open  it will through the duration for all three to gether, i wants to get all three duration separately , so i can know which one is slow